# Url issue in safari browser related to fragment identifier (#)

Tags: php, wordpress, safari

I am working on a Wordpress site using the Vanilla forum plugin. I found HTML code below after  I checked firebug:

```
  <ul>
  <li><a href="http://knowmoretv.com/discussions-4#/discussion/73/diets-that-work">Diets That Work</a></li>
  <li><a href="http://knowmoretv.com/discussions-4#/discussion/72/heart-disease-support">Heart Disease Support</a></li>
  </ul>
```

I have only have a problem in Safari browser; when I click either of the first two links, it goes to `http://knowmoretv.com/discussions-4/` but if use any other browser it goes to `http://knowmoretv.com/discussions-4/#/discussion/73/diets-that-work` (or heart-disease-support, as I'd expect).

Should i use jQuery code redirect # to /# in safari browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have fixed that problem by jQuery for Safari browser

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){

 $.browser.safari = $.browser.webkit && !window.chrome;
 if ($.browser.safari) {

    $("a").click(function(event){

       event.preventDefault();

       var urlval = $(this).attr('href').split('#');

       var urlvals = urlval[0]+'/#'+urlval[1];

       var pathname = window.location.pathname;

       if(pathname == '/discussions-4/')
       {

         window.location.assign(urlvals);

         window.location.reload(true);

       }
       else{

         window.location.assign(urlvals);

       }

       });
   }

  });
  </script>
```